# Load a Single Large Python Dictionary Encoded as Json Without Killing Memory Usage?

Tags: python, json

I've seen a lot of similar questions to this, but nothing that really matched. Most other questions seemed to relate to speed. What I'm experiencing is a single json dictionary that sits in a 1.1gig file on my local box taking up all of my 16 gigabytes of memory when I try to load it using anything along the lines of:

```
f = open(some_file, "rb")
new_dictionary = json.load(f)
```

This happens regardless of what json library I use (I've tried ujson, json, yajl), and regardless of whether I read things in as a byte stream or not. This makes absolutely no sense to me. What's with the crazy memory usage, and how do I get around it?

In case it helps, the dictionary is just a bunch of nested dictionaries all having ints point to other ints. A sample looks like:

```
{"0":{"3":82,"4":503,"15":456},"956":{"56":823,"678":50673,"35":1232}...}
```

**UPDATE:** When I run this with simplejson, it actually only takes up 8 gigs. No idea why that one takes up so much less than all the others.

**UPDATE 2:** So I did some more investigation. I loaded up my dictionary with simplejson, and tried converting all the keys to ints (per Liori's suggestion that strings might take up more space). Space stayed the same at 8 gigs. Then I tried Winston Ewert's suggestion of running a gc.collect(). Space still remained at 8 gigs. Finally, annoyed and curious, I pickled my new data structure, exited Python, and reloaded. Lo and behold, it still takes up 8 gigs. I guess Python just wants that much space for a big 2d dictionary. Frustrating, for sure, but at least now I know it's not a JSON problem so long as I use simplejson to load it.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what's in the JSON object? I.e. lots of lists? dictionaries? strings? floats? Python objects will probably take more memory than the one-disk version, although 16 times as much seems a little suspicious.

Comment: There's a lot of overhead in a Python object. I'm willing to bet that much data just takes that much space.

Comment: I wrote this thing with Python originally, and it fit in memory just fine before I wrote it. There's definitely something weird going on.

Comment: So you have a dictionary in memory, `json.dump()` it to a file, and when you then `json.load()` the same file, memory use increases sixteenfold?

Comment: Yes, except it's only 16 fold from when it was on disk. I don't remember exactly what it took up in memory originally, and I can't check because it took hours to build.

Comment: I guess the keys were also ints originally? JSON requires keys to be strings, and so `json.load` does that. I wonder if this alone could eat so much RAM. Also, JSON isn't good for so big structures. You should try pickle instead, I guess…

Comment: Pickle was the original plan, but my company has some ugly Perl programs that want this data as well, so I switched to JSON, so any language can get at it easily.

Comment: My guess is that it is unavoidably taking up that much memory while you're reading it in. Have you thought about dropping it into a sqlite database? At least then it will be easier to get at individual chunks of the data.

Comment: Gabe, your comment was correct. Can you put it in as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabe really figured this out in a comment, but since it's been a few months and he hasn't posted it as an answer, I figured I should just answer my own question, so posterity sees that there is an answer.

Anyway, the answer is that a 2d dictionary just takes up that much space in Python. Each one of those dictionaries winds up with some space overhead, and since there are a lot of them, it balloons up from 1.1 gig to 8 gigs, and there's nothing you can do about it except try to use a different data structure or get more ram.

Comment: You can actually use less ram by not loading the whole file in memory, using streaming parsers as @Marco suggested would allow you to act during parsing on what to keep in memory and what to dump. If you make your code a little smarter you do not need to buy more RAM.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with a streaming API:

http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/

of which there are a couple of python wrappers.

https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl/

https://github.com/pykler/yajl-py

Answer (score 2):

A little experimentation on my part suggests that calling `gc.collect()` after the json object has been parsed drops memory usage to where it was when the object was originally constructed.

Here is the results I get for memory usage on a smaller scale:

```
Build. No GC
762912
Build. GC
763000
Standard Json. Unicode Keys. No GC
885216
Standard Json. Unicode Keys. GC
744552
Standard Json. Int Keys. No GC
885216
Standard Json. Int Keys. GC
744724
Simple Json. Unicode Keys. No GC
894352
Simple Json. Unicode Keys. GC
745520
Simple Json. Int Keys. No GC
894352
Simple Json. Int Keys. GC
744884
```

Basically, running gc.collect() appears to cleanup some sort of garbage producing during the JSON parsing process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm about to say this but json is actually a very simple format, it wouldn't be too difficult to build your own parser.

That said, it would only makes sense if:

- You don't need the full dictionary at the end (i.e., you can consume the data as you read it)
- You have a good idea what sort of structure the data is in (an arbitrarily deep dictionary would make this much more difficult)